# Правильно ли я использую игнорирование ошибки для sqlite3?

Tags: python, sqlite3

Мне нужно, чтобы питон игнорировал ошибку повторения данных в колонках и добавлял одинаковые данные в бд. Я использую вот такое решение:

```
c.execute(
            "INSERT or IGNORE INTO Programm_system (data_nachala, modul, language_modul, programmers_modul) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)",
            (data_nachala1, modul1, language_modul1, programmers_modul1))
        conn.commit()
```

Ошибки не выдаёт, однако и данные не добавляются, как можно исправить.
Следом возникает второй вопрос: как можно **запретить** повторение данных **только** по 1 столбцу? - Поясню, допустим есть 3 столбца, и когда я ввожу в них данные, они миогли бы повторяться в 2 столбцах, но в 3 должны быть уникальными.

Comment: `INSERT INTO Programm_system (data_nachala, modul, language_modul, programmers_modul) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?) on conflict do nothing;`

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1474675/%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87e%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%8f-%d0%b2-sql-%d0%b1%d0%b0%d0%b7%d1%83/1474714#1474714 Вот тут посмотрите

Comment: Спасибо. Теперь норм.